# Updating a document that has both belongs_to and has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, nomethoderror

I'm having trouble with my Rails/Mongoid app whenever I'm updating my documents.

I have three collections: `owners`, `vessels` and `modifications`.

```
class Owner
    include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :vessels
    field :name, type: String
    field :uprn, type: String
end

class Vessel
    include Mongoid::Document   
    belongs_to :owner
    has_many :modifications
    field :name, type: String
    attr_accessor :uprn
end

class Modification
    include Mongoid::Document   
    belongs_to :vessel  
    field :change_description, type: String
end
```

The idea is that each owner owns several vessels (there's a `has_many`, `belongs_to` relationship going on) and that there are several modifications which were done on each vessel (again, `has_many`, `belongs_to` relationship).

Creating owners, vessels and changes works just fine. When I try to update an owner, it works. If I try to update a modification, it also works. However, the moment I try to update the vessel that belongs to an owner and has some modifications done on it, I'm getting this error:

> NoMethodError in OwnersController#update
>
> undefined method `values' for # Mongoid::Criteria:0xb50d49d0

Here's the code that throws this error. Besides just modifying the data stored in the document, it also checks if the owner's changed (that's where the uprn field comes in) and alters the owner_id accordingly.

```
def update
    @vessel = Vessel.find(params[:id])
    @owner = Owner.find_by(uprn: params[:vessel][:uprn])
    if @owner.present?
        @vessel.owner_id = @owner.id
        if @vessel.update(vessel_params)
            redirect_to @vessel
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    else
        @vessel.errors[:base] << "There is no owner with the UPRN entered."
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Note that this only happens when there's a 1-n association between the two. If there's just one modification per vessel (so a `has_one`, `belongs_to` association) it works just fine. Same deal if I try to embed - 1-1 embeds update fine, 1-n embeds report the same error. It also works fine if there's just the vessel and its modifications (no association with the owner). The moment vessel is associated with both the owner and its modifications, this thing happens.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 4.2.1, Mongo 2.6.1 and Mongoid 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the way to fix this is to remove the `has_many :vessels` from Owner and `has_many: modifications` from Vessel, so that the resulting code looks like:

```
class Owner
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :name, type: String
    field :uprn, type: String
end

class Vessel
    include Mongoid::Document   
    belongs_to :owner
    field :name, type: String
    attr_accessor :uprn
end

class Modification
    include Mongoid::Document   
    belongs_to :vessel  
    field :change_description, type: String
end
```

After removing these two lines, the app works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problems it seems to be the field name, if any field include the word "change" the error will appears. Hope this help others.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This should actually be a comment, not an answer. You can comment once you earn enough reputation. Thanks.